# How to set constant dynamically in Ruby on Rails helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this (simplified) helper function in Rails:

```
include Constants

def link_to_neighbour(direction, path)
  symbol = direction.upcase.constantize
  link_to symbol, path
end
```

In `lib/constants` I defined these constants:

```
PREVIOUS = "<<"
NEXT = ">>"
```

Yet when I use something like this in one of my views...

```
<%= link_to_neighbour('next', @user, user_path(@user)) %>
```

... I constantly get this error:

```
NameError
uninitialized constant NEXT
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure about the solultion to your problem, but why are you using so complicated solution just to print two chars? Isn't it better to go for translations maybe?

Comment: The problem occurs probably because your constants are namespaced, so you should refer them as `Constants::PREVIOUS` and `Constants::NEXT`.

Comment: I tried that already. I am using other constants in that same file too and never needed the `Constants::` prefix there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `const_missing` hook of ruby.

```
def self.const_missing(name)
  const_set(name, some_value)
end
```

but the problem here seems that you have not loaded 'lib/constants.rb' file in application.rb of your application.

Put this line in your 'config/application.rb'

```
# Autoload lib/ folder including all subdirectories
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

If you don't want to put this line in your 'config/application.rb' then move constants.rb from lib to your 'config/initializers/' folder. Your Rails application loads
each file there automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should look like this:

```
def link_to_neighbour(direction, path)
  symbol = Object.const_get(direction.upcase)
  link_to symbol, path
end
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `constants.yml`

```
directions:
  PREVIOUS: "<<"
  NEXT: ">>"
```

this way I can use a tree of constants.

then in an initializer:

```
Constants = OpenStruct.new YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/constants.yml')).with_indifferent_access
```

then in the helper method:

```
def link_to_neighbour(direction, path)
  symbol = Constants.directions[direction.upcase]
  link_to symbol, path
end
```